# Filtering classes in build.sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

[Play enhancer docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayEnhancer#Configuration) say it can be enabled for specific classes/packages. It can be done (I assume in build.sbt) this way:

```
sources in (Compile, playEnhancerGenerateAccessors) := {
  ((javaSource in Compile).value / "models" ** "*.java").get
}
```

I am not used to sbt/scala and I am wondering how do I provide multiple packages in such filtering. It would be even nicer if I could choose classes with specified annotations. Is it possible?

EDIT:
So the question was motivated by intention to increase compilation speed of Play Framework project. Turns out even when I enhance only specific package(s), the compilation speed is basically the same. It is strange because turning PlayEnchancer completely off, cuts compilation time of my project almost by half (30 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scoped `sources` setting stores a set of files for that Play Enhancer task and this example just filters files with the given pattern:

- `(javaSource in Compile).value` should be `src/main/java/` directory in your project
- `/ "models"` means you're looking only in `src/main/java/models/`
- `** "*.java"` searching all subdirectories for any files with the `.java` extension
- `.get` just evaluates the list of files matching the pattern

If you wanted to combine several patterns, you could do it with `+++` and `---` operators:

```
sources in (Compile, playEnhancerGenerateAccessors) := {
  val green = base / "green" ** "*.java"
  val blue  = base / "blue" ** "*.java"
  val red   = base / ** "*red*"
  (green +++ blue --- red).get
}
```

In sbt these patterns are called *Path Finders* and you can read how to use them in the sbt docs for [Paths](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Paths.html). As this is just about filtering files by their path/name, I don't think you can select classes with specified annotations this way.